# Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame

Tags: javascript, hash

Am getting below error when i try to set the hash value for one server url from a page in a iframe which belongs to another server.

Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL "Server 1 URL" from frame with URL ""Server 2 URL"". Domains, protocols and ports must match.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is to avoid XSS (Cross-site scripting) vulnerabilities.  This is a normal security measure, and you should avoid it if you're developing professionally.  We had a workaround before but this is because we own "Server 1" and "Server 2". The workaround is for Server 1 to act as a proxy server and feed all data from Server 2, this allowed us to inject javascript to the iframe,

Comment: Thanks Manny.
But due to this error my further code doesnt work.. Once clicked on submit button i set the hash value for another server page and the page is redirected to the one where the hash value is set. But once the above error occurs my pages doesnt redirects.